# Scraping a javascript / json object from a webpage using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to get the HTML of a webpage. That works fine so far. But what I really want are the contents of this javascript chunk inside the HTML, which is encapsulated with `<script type="text/javascript">` and then inside that tag, eventually there is a giant array thing that has a lot of `{}` brackets, and I believe this is a JSON array?

Is there a way I can try to extract that entire array from within the HTML?

Comment: *Unless* it is in a String and parsed with JSON.parse it is a JavaScript Object Literal. JSON just happens to be closely based on such JavaScript syntax (with restrictions and subtle differences).

Comment: In Javascript, `{}` (braces) indicate an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) and `[]` (brackets) indicate an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: `import json` then `foo = json.loads(objectText)` : [18.2. json — JSON encoder and decoder](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the function `json.loads`.

```
>>> import json
>>> obj = json.loads('{"a": 12, "b": null}')
>>> obj
{'b': None, 'a': 12}
```